# Add watchers to an issue if they are not members of the project

Tags: redmine

According to this: http://www.redmine.org/issues/5159

I should be able to add any user that exists in our Redmine to any issue even if they are a not a member of the project. However, I only am seeing members of the project in the watchers list. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When testing this on demo.redmine.org, I can let anybody watch issues in my test project. On the other hand, it really only works, if the user is also able to see the issue, i.e. the project needs to be public. Otherwise, the watcher will not receive notifications.

Also you need to use the watcher autocompleter to see non-members. Without starting a search only the project members are listed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin exactly for this purpose: https://github.com/maxrossello/redmine_extended_watchers

I just have installed on 3.0.3 version and it works.